# The Strain Vampire Vigilante and Theory

Tags: analysis, the-strain

In [The Strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strain_%28TV_series%29) Season 1 Episode 7, [For Services Rendered](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3515200/), we see what appears to be a group of vigilante vampires. What is their relationship to other vampires like The Master and his minions?

I think there are 3 categories of vampires; the master, the minions and those who somehow found a way to break the will of the master controlling them to kill (like the vigilante group we saw).